# mysql: how to put row data into one return column

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm not sure how to ask this question or what is the right "keyword" for it to search/google.
what i have here is

```
=========================
=   ID   =   Running#   =
=========================
=   A    =      3       =
=   A    =      4       =
=   A    =      5       =
=   E    =      6       =
=   E    =      3       =
=   G    =      4       =
=   G    =      7       =
=   T    =      3       =
=========================
```

What i wish to get the return like
A,E,T in one string, where they having running# of 3

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** for this,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID)
FROM tablename
Where Running = 3
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it work well for me, and i also work with GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ID)), surprise me when i first try on your statement

Comment: @user1493339 `distinct`, when you want to have different value in the list :D